# How to save email attachments in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, attachment, pop3

How can I, using C#, Download an email attachment from my mail (for instance gmail)?

Comment: This link helped me to resolve the same problem, but this has 30 day trial. http://www.example-code.com/csharp/pop3_saveAttachments.asp Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
 //  Firstly you might want to use POP3Class which is mail support class.

     POP3Class Pop3= new POP3Class();
     pop3.DoConnect("your.mail.server",110,"username","password");
     pop3.GetStat();


  //  and then you can use the below code for storing an attachment.

     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage ();
     Mail.Load (args[0]);

     Console.WriteLine (
     "Message contains {0} attachments.", 
     mail.Attachments.Count
     );

    // If message has no attachments, just exit 
    if (mail.Attachments.Count == 0)
    return 0;

    foreach (Attachment attachment in mail.Attachments)
   {
   // Save the file 
   Console.WriteLine ("Saving '{0}' ({1}).", 
   attachment.FileName, attachment.MediaType);
   attachment.Save (attachment.FileName);
   }


// Hope that helps.
```

Comment: I don't have such methods and properties in `attachment` class, did you used some 3rd parties libs?

Comment: where can i get POP3Class library ?

Answer (score -3):

Following code is taken from [Extract Attachments sample](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/sample-extract-attachments.aspx) which comes with our [Rebex Mail](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/) component. Downloading from a POP3 server is covered in the [HOWTO: Download emails from a GMail account in C#](http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2007/05/14/howto-download-emails-from-gmail-account-in-csharp.aspx) blogpost.

```
// Load mail message from disk 
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage ();
mail.Load (args[0]);

Console.WriteLine (
    "Message contains {0} attachments.", 
    mail.Attachments.Count
);

// If message has no attachments, just exit 
if (mail.Attachments.Count == 0)
    return 0;

foreach (Attachment attachment in mail.Attachments)
{
    // Save the file 
    Console.WriteLine ("Saving '{0}' ({1}).", 
     attachment.FileName, attachment.MediaType);
    attachment.Save (attachment.FileName);
}
```