# Using POP3 how can we download excel attachment

Tags: c#

The below code is working for CSV file but when we use the same code to read excel file it is returning different letters in the file

```
foreach (MimeAttachment attach in msg.Attachments)
{
if (attach.Filename != "")
{
//read data from attachment
string myString = attach.Body.Replace("=\r\n", ""); //to eliminate the '=\r\n' from email attachemnt
Byte[] b = GetBytes(myString);

// save attachment to disk
System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream(b, false);
FileStream outStream = new FileStream(DownloadFilePath + "\\" + attach.Filename, FileMode.Create);
mem.WriteTo(outStream);
mem.Close();
outStream.Flush();
outStream.Close();
}
}
```

ex:

```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```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
foreach (OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart attachment in attachments)
                        {
                            if (attachment != null)
                            {
                                string ext = attachment.FileName.Split('.')[1];

                                Filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                                FileInfo file = new FileInfo((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Downloaded//") + Filename + ".csv" );

                                // Check if the file already exists
                                if (!file.Exists)
                                {
                                    attachment.Save(file);
                                }

                            }
                  }
```

or try this

[How to save email attachments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040321/how-to-save-email-attachments-to-local-hard-disk-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you try your code for Excel attachment, my code also working for CSV the problem is with Excel

Comment: @Ashaar did u try  this? are you using any dll to fetch mails?

Comment: Yes I am using 'smtpop.dll' 
In your case what is the dll you are using also is it opensource or need to purchase

Comment: Thanks. Yes by using the OpenPop we can perform the file download as it is.